# Ruby Uninitialized Constant when running rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

> ```
> uninitialized constant in blah/blah/add_feed_id_to_entry_states.rb:6:in `up'
> ```

```
class AddFeedIdToEntryStates < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :entry_states, :feed_id, :integer
    add_index :entry_states, :feed_id

    EntryState.find_each do |entry_state| 
      entry_state.feed_id = entry_state.entry.feed_id
      entry_state.save!
    end
  end  

  def down
    remove_column :entry_states, :feed_id
  end
end
```

Can anyone see what's wrong on line 6? "EntryState.find_each"  using ruby 2.0

Comment: what is your model name and post your routes.rb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two solutions to this problem. Either explicitly add

```
require 'entry_state'
```

at the top of your migration, or add a dummy-definition (so that your migration will still work if `EntryState` gets changed a lot in later migrations:

```
class EntryState < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :entry

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should <strike>never</strike> try not to include models in migrations.  The point of migration code is that once its committed to master, it doesn't change.

Think about what would happen if you drastically changed your  `EntryState` model.  Your migration could potentially fail, and creating a db from scratch would be a huge pain. It's definitely not worth it.

Instead, you should put that sort of data population code in a seed file or run it in the console.

But, for this specific situation, have you thought about using delegate?

```
class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :entries
  has_many :entry_states, :through => :entries
end

class Entry < ActiveRescord::Base
  belongs_to :feed
  has_many :entry_states
end

class EntryState < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :entry

  delegate :feed, :to => :entry, :allow_nil => true
end
```

Unless I'm missing something, this would solve your problem.

Comment: Well, I do not agree, if you change your database structurally, and hence you need to change the data along with it, it belongs in a migration.

Comment: "never" was perhaps too strong a word. However, I think you should avoid mixing data-population logic with migration logic when possible. In this situation, there are definitely better alternatives.

Comment: Agreed, avoid it. But this is not about data-population: that is what seeds are for. But if your datamodel changes, existing data has to be changed as well to maintain the integrity of the datamodel. That is exactly what a migration is for.